# How do we prove there is no natural number between $a$ and its successor $a\texttt{+}\texttt{+}$?

Tags: solution-verification, natural-numbers, peano-axioms

Let $a,b$ be natural numbers. Then $a < b$ if and only if $a\texttt{+}\texttt{+}\leq b$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

If $a < b$, we may suppose by contradiction that $a\texttt{+}\texttt{+} > b$. Thus we conclude that $a < b < a\texttt{+}\texttt{+}$, which is impossible, because there is no natural number between $a$ and $a\texttt{+}\texttt{+}$.

Conversely, if $a\texttt{+}\texttt{+}\leq b$, one has that $a < a\texttt{+}\texttt{+}\leq b$, and $a  < b$. That is because $a\texttt{+}\texttt{+} = a + 1 > a$ by definition of order, where it has been used the fact that $a\texttt{+}\texttt{+} = (a+0)\texttt{+}\texttt{+} = a + 0\texttt{+}\texttt{+} = a + 1$.

My question is: how do we prove there is no natural number between $a$ and $a\texttt{+}\texttt{+}$?

Comment: What's $a{+}+$? The successor of $a$?

Comment: Presumably, yes.  Using [`++` notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators) is common in programming languages to take a value and increment it by one, updating the value in the process.  (*note the distinction between `i++` and `++i` where the value is either updated before the return or after the return*)

Comment: @egreg, yes, it means the successor of $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me use $a^+$ for the successor, or the argument would be very cumbersome to write.

Saying that $a<b$ is the same as saying that $b=a+c$ for some $c>0$. Since $c>0$, we have $c=d^{+}$ and so
$$
b=a+d^{+}=a^++d
$$
Therefore $a^+\le b$.

Conversely, if $a^+\le b$, then $b=a^++c$ for some $c$. Hence $b=a+c^+$ and so $a<b$, because $c^+>0$.

This relies only on $x+y^+=x^++y$, that you can prove by induction.